# Best practice for static page elements in django

Tags: django

I have some page elements that don't change often and are displayed on every page like some adbars, footer content and such.

I want to change settings for this elements in my admin interface, so I have models for them.

Is there a best practice in django to deal with these elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, no. You're describing a singleton pattern, so you might want to implement a singleton model type:

```
class SingletonModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = 1
        super(SingletonModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

That will ensure that any model that inherits from that class can only ever have one member and that it can't be deleted. Other than that, I would suggest combining everything into just one model called something like `SiteSettings` with fields for header, footer, etc, instead of separate model for each.

Comment: I ended up using this suggestion. Furthermore I defined a custom assignment tag which is passed to my base template spitting out all my static widgets and elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) to add them to the context and use a simple caching mechanism so you don't have to hit the db every time like, http://eflorenzano.com/blog/2008/11/28/drop-dead-simple-django-caching/

Answer (score -1):

Hard to answer - what exactly are you asking?

You can display these models in your base template. You can use caching to cut down on database calls.